# Request specific connection strings in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

An ASP.NET Core MVC application uses virtual directory and cookie specific connection strings:

- http://example.com/database1

  - Cookie value 1

    - should use connection string: `Database=db1;Search_Path=company1`
  - Cookie value 2

    - should use connection string: `Database=db1;Search_Path=company2`
- http://example.com/database2

  - Cookie value 1

    - should use connection string: `Database=db2;Search_Path=company1`

[This Entity Framework Core tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-rp/intro?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio) contains sample code for setting connection string for an entire application:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddRazorPages();

    services.AddDbContext<SchoolContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("SchoolContext")));
}
```

How to use request specific connection strings?

**Update**

I tried code in answer and added the following code to Home controller:

```
public class HomeController 
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {

            using (var context = new SchoolContext(new DbContextOptions<SchoolContext>()))
            {
                var commandText = "INSERT into maksetin(maksetin) VALUES (1)";
                context.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw(commandText);
            }
```

This throws error

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'No database provider has been configured for
 this DbContext. 
A provider can be configured by overriding the 'DbContext.OnConfiguring' method or by
  using 'AddDbContext' on the application service provider. 
If 'AddDbContext' is used, then also ensure that your DbContext type accepts a DbContextOptions<TContext> object in
 its constructor and passes it to the base constructor for DbContext.'
```

Breakpoint in line

```
  IHttpContextAccessor http = sp.GetRequiredService<IHttpContextAccessor>();
```

does not occur. So code in answer is not called. How to force it call ?

Comment: Is the number of different connection strings limited? E.g. are there just these three different databases? Or are there a theoretically unlimited number of databases that will be dynamically set up at run-time?

Comment: There is unlimited number of databases containing unlimited number of schemas. Virtual directoy to database mapping is in appsettings.json file. Scheme to access is read from cookie sent from user browser.

Comment: @poke I posted it as separate question in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65478936/create-database-context-from-cookie-in-entity-framework-core

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do both of these databases have the exact same Schema?

The quick and dirty way would be to just create two different DbContext Schemas that inherit from your base Schema, and register them separately to their own connection strings in your `Startup.cs`

IE:

```
public abstract MyBaseDbContext : DbContext 
{ 
   // Setup your DB schema here, assuming both databases use the same Schema
}

public FirstDbContext : MyBaseDbContext { ... }

public SecondDbContext : MyBaseDbContext { ... }
```

And then in Startup:

```
services.AddDbContext<FirstDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("First")));
services.AddDbContext<SecondDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("Second")));
```

And then in controllers:

```
private FirstDbContext FirstDbContext { get; }
private SecondDbContext SecondDbContext { get; }

public SomeController(FirstDbContext firstDbContext, SecondDbContext secondDbContext) 
{ 
      FirstDbContext = firstDbContext;
      SecondDbContext = secondDbContext;
}


public IActionResult SomeEndpoint()
{
    // Use FirstDbContext here to do things within Database 1
}

public IActionResult SomeOtherEndpoint()
{
    // Use SecondDbContext here to do things within Database 1
}

public IActionResult AnotherEndpoint()
{
    // You can even use both DbContexts if you so choose here to 
    // perform logic involving data in both DBs!
}
```

If your databases dont even have the same schema, then you can just ignore the whole `MyBaseDbContext` thing, and just define two distinct FooDbContext classes and register both of them to their associated connection strings.

Comment: Singe databases contian multiple schemes, all of them have same structure. Context class contains only one scheme. Web application user can select scheme and this selection is stored in cookie. In Npgsql connection string search_path should set to scheme selected by user. Same context class is used to access data in all shemes. Scheme used is specifed in connection string search_path paramater.  Your answer does not allow to set search_path in connection string from httprequest cookie.

Comment: See the Startup.cs code, you should be able to set your search path there.

Comment: Startup code is running only once when application starts.  Application has many users having different scheme cookie values. Also user can select other scheme. It this case scheme cookie value will change. So it looks like it cannot be placed into startup.cs. How to inject cookie value to EF DbContext constructor ?

Comment: I posted it in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65478936/create-database-context-from-cookie-in-entity-framework-core